# Mime detection configuration settings missing ?

Tags: 7

I installed [MimeDetect](http://drupal.org/project/mimedetect) module in my server, added necessary configuration to the settings.php file and also enabled that module.
When I try to configure the "Mime Detection" I get the following message:

> The MimeDetect module is using PHP's fileinfo extension to detect
>   MIME types. There are no settings for the extension.

Is there anything I missed out or needs to be configure?

Comment: Could you please use tags to indicate what is your Drupal version. [6] or [7] ? Have you installed the PHP FileInfo extension library ? http://php.net/fileinfo

Comment: i installed that fileinfo library but still i face the same issue

Comment: What PHP version do you use ? If you view phpinfo(); is it displaying the fileinfo extension? Did you see and try to add http://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.configuration.php ?